# Apache Virtual Host - Mod Proxy issues

Tags: apache, proxy, centos, virtual, host

Not too au fait with Apache, have setup simple virtual hosts before without an issue.  Seem to be having a bizarre one, working with 1 IP address and multiple servers.

My second virtual host seems to only look at the first 2 entries and ignores the rest.  I have mapped out what I want to happen and how my vhost file looks and the second image is what is happening.

[How my virtual hosts are setup and envision the routing to act](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Chdb.png)

[How it's currently operating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pIbi.png)

Now it maybe not right using virtual hosts on both servers?

Not too au fait with Apache, have setup simple virtual hosts before without an issue.  Seem to be having a bizarre one, working with 1 IP address and multiple servers.

My second virtual host seems to only look at the first 2 entries and ignores the rest.  I have mapped out what I want to happen and how my vhost file looks and the second image is what is happening.

Server1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server1.domain.com
    ServerAlias x.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    ServerAlias y.domain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://server2
    ProxyPassReverse / http://server2

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    ServerAlias z.domain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://server2
    ProxyPassReverse / http://server2

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    ServerAlias w.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
   ProxyPass / http://server2
   ProxyPassReverse / http://server2
</VirtualHost>
```

Server 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    ServerAlias z.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/z
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    ServerAlias w.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/w
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.domain.com
    ServerAlias y.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/y
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your configuration right. As all your ServerNames read "server2,domain.com" on server1 virtual host config, they actually are conflicting. Thus only the first entry likely is to apply. Same with server2 config. Could you add how this setting is to be called via http?

Comment: So the entry point into the network is into server 1 as I only have 1 public facing IP address.  Why I am using server 1 to route into server 2 is because I don't want to have to use different port numbers for ease of use, ege server1.domain.com:81.  So any of the selected subdomains z, w and y. Should just be directed to the 2nd server and from there server 2 virtual hosts will direct the subdomains to the correct folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid giving the same Servername to any two VirtualHost entries. Using x,y,z, etc names is perfectly ok (assumed all resolve to the one IP address from external users).

For simplicity (of maintenance and managing the configuration) also avoid mixing "standard" server configuration (e.g. x on server1) with VirtualHost ones. Any accessible area on your web namespace should be configured via VirtualHost. (The first one in your configuration becomming "default" in that case.)

Using VirtualHosts on both servers is not a problem by itself. You just need to ensure the ServerName from the original HTTP request is correctly being forwarded and arriving at server2. For this you need to add

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

to your VirtualHost configurations.

It might, however, be easier to give up the name based VirtualHosts usage with server2 and turn to using different ip address or ports for the individual (logical) hosts. Server2 is (at least by concept) an internal setting and not visible to the "external" side. Thus, ease of use is not truly attributable

Comment: Thanks for your comments, really trying to avoid using ports and just have everything against a subdomain.

Comment: Whatever you do, server2 needs basic information in order to distinguish your various virtual hosts. Otherwise they just are located to the single matching entry (e.g the first one). This is what you observe...

Comment: Ok, so my issue had to do with the firewall/ports.  First issue was ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse was  "/ http://server2" which needed to be "/ http://server2/", so missing the last dash. In addition to that, I am translating 81 to 80 for this server.  So ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse looked like "/ http://server2:81/"